# Resource Gantt with AnyChart can't change chart height

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, anychart

I want to use **AnyChart** to show a resource **Gantt**. Everything is OK but the chart height is small (only 150 px) and I can't make it bigger in my browser.

This works on **playground** (https://playground.anychart.com/docs/7.13.1/samples/GANTT_Chart_01-plain) even with my data.

I copied exactly the same code to my project, the chart only shows 150 px height.

**JavaScript**

```
    var treeData = anychart.data.tree(data, anychart.enums.TreeFillingMethod.AS_TABLE);

    // chart type
    chart = anychart.ganttResource();
    //chart = anychart.fromJson(ganttdata);
    chart.height(800);

    // chart container
    chart.container("devschedule");

    // chart position
    chart.bounds(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

    // chart data
    chart.data(treeData);

    // data tree width
    chart.splitterPosition(170);

    var dataGrid = chart.dataGrid();

    // settings for first column
    dataGrid.column(0).width(30).title().text("#");

    // settings for the second column
    dataGrid.column(1).width(140).format(function(item) {
    return item.get("name");
    }).title().text("Person");
    // initiate drawing
    chart.draw();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" height="500px">
  <div id="devschedule">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Chart]

Is there anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: additional findings: if I remove the <!doctype html> at the very beginning of the html file, the chart height is correct(full page). WHY <!DOCTYPE HTML> affect the chart height?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that the chart's container can be set as

- HTML element's ID (or as HTML element itself)
- Anychart Stage. Usage samples are here: https://docs.anychart.com/7.13.1/Dashboards/Stage-Based_Layout

If container is set as ID (`chart.container("devschedule");`), the chart creates its own [stage](https://api.anychart.com/7.13.1/anychart.graphics.vector.Stage) to be rendered inside it. By default, stage takes bounds of its **div-container**. And the chart takes bounds of its **stage**.

This is the first way of how to set the chart's height: just specify the div's size in correct CSS way:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <div id="devschedule" style="height: 500px; width: 600px">
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="height: 500px; width: 600px">
    <div id="devschedule">
    </div>
</div>
```

The second thing you should note about chart's heigh is the fact that chart's bounds are bounds in **stage**. It means that

1. Line of code `chart.bounds(0, 0, "100%", "100%");` is useless: as I said before, chart takes bounds of stage by default.
2. `chart.height(800);` is absolutely the same as `chart.bounds(0, 0, "100%", 800);`.
3. `chart.bounds(0, 0, "100%", "100%");` completely overrides `chart.height(800);` line of code because `chart.bounds` is set after `chart.height`.
4. In most cases `chart.bounds()` method is used for dashboarding purposes to add two or more charts on stage and avoid overlapping. It means that if your DIV-container has 600px height, stage takes 600px height as well by default, setting `chart.height(800)` will make the bottom of chart invisible because of overflow.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried, add style to <div id = "devschedule" style="height: 500px; width: 600px"> works. But add to <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="height: 500px; width: 600px">
    <div id="devschedule">
    </div>
</div> doesn't work. it still show only 150 px height.

Comment: I suppose, 150px is just a default div height for your browser and inner div can't define its own height. Anyway, it is an issue of CSS because anychart works the way I described above. Good luck!